# Forming mux demux trees by cascading using strobe

Tags: multiplexer

**Some definitions**

- When implementing a M:1 multiplexer using N:1 multiplexers, where M>N, we cascade N:1 multiplexers, which forms **tree of multiplexers**.
- Similarly, when implementing 1:M de-multiplexer using 1:N de-multiplexer, where M>N, we cascade 1:N de-multiplexers, which forms **tree of de-multiplexers**.
- **Strobe input** is an enable input which is used to enable multiplexer, de multiplexer (or any components in the given context) etc.
- **Cascading using strobing** refers to forming MUX and deMUX tree using most significant bit / Mth bit of target MUX or deMUX as a strobe input for two MUX/deMUX:

For example, a 32:1 multiplexer can be implemented using 16:1 multiplexers by cascading using strobe input as follows:

[image]

Note that A is MSB of target 32:1 MUX and is used to drive strobe/enable input of two 16:1 MUXes. For M1, A is a strobe, for M2, A' is the strobe.

**Doubts**

I have following questions about cascading using strobing:

1. Is cascading MUXes with strobing only possible when we have M=N+1?
2. Can strobe cascaded MUX trees have only two MUXes and a single level of MUXes?
3. Do strobe cascaded MUX trees always require two input OR gate?
4. Is cascading deMUXes with strobing only possible when we have M=N+1, similar to strobe cascaded MUX trees?
5. Can strobe cascaded deMUX trees have only two deMUXes and single level of deMUXes similar to strobe cascaded MUX trees?

I feel "yes" is the answer for first four questions and "no" is the answer to fifth question. But I need confirmation.

I believe "no" is the answer to fifth question because in below 1:32 deMUX using 1:4 deMUXes, I can replace deMUX on left most level/level 1 with Din acting as a strobe for deMUXes at level 2 and still form 1:32 deMUX. The tree ends up having 10 (>2) deMUXes and two levels, level 1 with two deMUXes and level 2 with 8 deMUXes.

[image]

Please add following tags: de-multiplexer, combinational-circuits

Comment: I'm curious...why is this important to you? Is it homework? It seems like an arcane way of designing large multiplexers/demultiplexers.

Comment: You are asking importance of what? The overall tree approach or the questions I asked. Related questions are usually asked in exams. I am preparing for exam. So want to know every details.

Comment: Also these are not homework problems. I had a lot of contemplation on these trees and then come up with these points which are not discussed in any text. So need confirmation.

Comment: The strobing is just a 1-bit decoder. If you want to cascade more multiplexers, you just need a wider decoder. You can also see the same circuitry used in each multiplexer. The select inputs go directly to a decoder that enables only one of the AND gates. You then use an OR gate to merge the inputs into a single output, since all other AND gates have output zero. Have a look at memory mapping. The same principles apply there.

Comment: I know first two statements of your comment. Didn't get sentences 3,4,5.Are you trying to explain functioning of multiplexer? Also didn't get what you mean by memory map. What about my doubts I numbered 1 to 5?